# Heroku CI with pytest-django fails - module "doesn't declare an explicit app_label"

Tags: django, pytest, cookiecutter-django, heroku-ci

I've deployed a Django app and would like to get Heroku CI setup. I have a suite of tests that run locally. On heroku CI test setup succeeds and then the test runner fails with the following error log (abbreviated):

```
==================================== ERRORS ====================================

________________________ ERROR collecting test session _________________________

.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:495: in _importconftest

    return self._conftestpath2mod[key]

E   KeyError: PosixPath('/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_dynamic_fixture/tests/conftest.py')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

...

.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:112: in __new__

    raise RuntimeError(

E   RuntimeError: Model class django_dynamic_fixture.models_sample_app.Publisher doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

As you can see, this error originates in an imported module (django_dynamic_fixture) which runs fine locally. I think this may be due to how heroku ci is configured and therefore I don't know what I can do to solve this issue.

The `doesn't declare an explicit app_label...` error is probably due to mixing absolute and relative imports, or from a missing `django.contrib.sites` app in the django settings file. However because the tests run locally, I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Have you checked your  `settings_dev.py` & `settings_prod.py` (supposing you have them separately) both have the app name in `INSTALLED APPS` list?

Comment: settings files and INSTALLED_APPS are ok - i can run tests locally specifying the settings.test file. It appears to be something on the heroku platform itself

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by using the `ignore` option.
Instead of using `ignore`, use `norecursedirs` instead.

Also, tests are run from the `app/` dir, so any `norecursedirs` should not include this dir, but only its children. e.g. `.heroku`, not `app/.heroku`